how to get shared content from app tray selection into app?
I've created this simple repo:
https://github.com/design-and-deliver/content-sharing
The only goals for this repo are:

Display the app icon in the app share tray so the user can share
info to the app via the share icon
The screen should write out the info that was shared from the external source

I have the ContentSharing app configured so that its icon displays in the phone share tray.  That is working in the current state of the repo.  But I'm having some problems with my #2 goal above.  ChatGPT has led me in a few different directions for this so I've developed the following components within the project which are designed to either Alert or write out the shared content to the screen:

IntentHandler
ShareBridge
ShareBridge2

I'm having problems achieving my #2 goal above though.  I'm sure that several people here have implemented this type of functionality in their RN apps before so hopefully I can get some feedback in regards to the gap here.  Thanks in advance!

explain what you mean by shared content, this question makes no sense, what content are you trying to share? what do you mean by content and share into a app? are you just wanting the app to collect whatever is on the clipboard?

Yeah - so for example - I copy/pasted the following text from the Share icon for an article in my Android news feed:
Should you buy a Macan or Cayenne? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=q30rG9G1f4Y
The sample repo displays the app for selection.   Now - after the app is selected - I want the text to be written out to the screen.  That's what I'm trying to do but I'm not sure how to go about doing that - which is what I'm asking for help for in this post.

alright I'll do my bet to give you an answer

I'll try help get you started.
you can read whatever is on the clipboard in javascript since you have react native, (idk maybe theres a specific RN module but Js Clipboard should work just fine)
const clipboardContents = await navigator.clipboard.read();

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read
if you've pasted a url and want to get its html content then you'll need to do a fetch to get the html content.
Often websites have tactics to combat this kind of scraping so you may need to get a server side script running that can spoof the user agent depending on what content you are wanting to copy.
and now we are in a grey area of legality so thats about as far as I should probably advise, but there are advanced technics documented on the web once you've got the basics going.
couple updates based on your clarification.
yes you can take out the JSON+LD data, this is data exposed from a website for giving content previews in searches.
https://json-ld.org/
If the website provides json+ld data you can use a server side service to collect it. heres one I found at the time of writing: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld-request
Share widgets as you mentioned usually work either by passing the url to the vendor and the vendor does the above on their side OR the vendor api asks for a payload to supply things like titles and images.

For the context of this post - I'm only trying to get a handle to the content captured when the user taps the Share icon.  Based on the source share implementation - I think this should be either:
1 - The url of the article
2 - The url and title of the article
This works as expected with an app like gmail - ie the text for the scenarios above get copied into the body of a new email.  Similarly - if I select the ContentSharing app icon from the share tray then I want to be able to toggle back to the ContentSharing app in my AVD emulator and see that text output to the screen.

ah yup that all good. in a share widget there is an integration with the platform thats sending the url to that page. The widget is just sharing the url and they receiving platform pulls the jsonld data from the url it received The content they are using is JSON+LD (json link data) that you are allowed to collect. I dont know you can do that without a backend service but there is a node based one available on github https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld-request

According to ChatGPT - seems like the Share implementation revolves around the use of "Intent" scaffolding.  That's what is used to display the Share icon in the tray - and apparently that is what is used to propagate the text.  maybe there is another way - but I would like to understand the "intent" approach - since that seems like a structured and common standard.  I just need a solution for Android atm.

the intent approach is for native applications, you are using react Native. I wouldn't rely too much on chatGPT it is only capable of delivering simple gists and half the time it gets confused between technologies. The intent option is also just for capturing the clipboard you still have to do the lifting to get the data out of the url yourself.

hmm thats interesting.  so the intent config in the sample repo that i provided does successfully display the app icon in the share tray.  i'll review your answer more closely tomorrow.  i'm new to this particular interaction so i'm not totally clear on how to conceptualize it - but sounds like the lib u referenced is designed to capture the text from the share icon, pass that text to the app icon ref in the app share tray, and then capture and propogate that text into the app component.  i'll need to dig into that a bit.  thanks!

ah with that comment I'm getting a better picture of what you're trying to do, so yeah those intent plugins will get your app in the shared tray, having another quick look at the react-native-receive-sharing-intent/utils.js I can see where it passes a url but doesnt look like it fetches the jsonld for the preview content (which is where the fetching of the preview content comes in if thats what you wre hoping to do next). the clipboard solution I gave only gets whatever is added to the clipboard but that doesnt cover files or showing up in the share tray, you were on the right path.

thanks daniel! sounds like u have expertise in this area.  i'll paypal u $20 if u can get that repo working end to end for me for that one particular isolated scenario.  ie selecting the ContentSharing icon in the share tray should result in the related url/title getting set to a local state variable in App.js which then gets written out to the screen.  i know your time and expertise is worth more than that - but you're already in there and that's all i got atm.

sorry bud can't put time in things like that, but you could try posting it up on fiver one of the freelancers probably has it templated. I;d suspect you need to do it with a backend service, have done this with a microservice in php before, it took a weekend to get going right. But never from the client, (maybe it's possible or maybe possible a sidecar app running node). Bit of research still required there.
